# Java <identifier> expected error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I get 20 errors in middle for loops when compiling this program; the following is only a snippet:

```
public static long[] bishopsMasks()
{
    long[] masks = new long[64];

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            long x = 0L;

            for (int a = i + 1, int b = j + 1; a < 7 && b < 7; a++, b++)
                x |= bit(a, b);

            for (int a = i + 1, int b = j - 1; a < 7 && b > 0; a++, b--)
                x |= bit(a, b);

            for (int a = i - 1, int b = j + 1; a > 0 && b < 7; a--, b++)
                x |= bit(a, b);

            for (int a = i - 1, int b = j - 1; a > 0 && b > 0; a--, b--)
                x |= bit(a, b);

            masks[i + j * 8] = x;
        }
    }

    return masks;
}
```

I just can't find anything wrong with it!

Comment: Please read [this](http://sscce.org) page, then update your question.

Comment: What lines show the error? What are the *exact* error messages? Do you have a bit method?

Answer (score 9):

You can't declare multiple variables in a for-loop initializer like this:

```
for (int a = i + 1, int b = j + 1; a < 7 && b < 7; a++, b++)
```

You can, however, do this (note the removal of `int` before `b`):

```
for (int a = i + 1, b = j + 1; a < 7 && b < 7; a++, b++)
```

However, that means the variables have to be the same type, of course.

See the [Java language specification section 14.14.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14) for more information.

Comment: Thanks John and all the comments below; the program works now! I got confused with C

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `int` before `b`.

```
public static long[] bishopsMasks()
{
    long[] masks = new long[64];

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            long x = 0L;

            for (int a = i + 1, b = j + 1; a < 7 && b < 7; a++, b++)
                x |= bit(a, b);

            for (int a = i + 1, b = j - 1; a < 7 && b > 0; a++, b--)
                x |= bit(a, b);

            for (int a = i - 1, b = j + 1; a > 0 && b < 7; a--, b++)
                x |= bit(a, b);

            for (int a = i - 1, b = j - 1; a > 0 && b > 0; a--, b--)
                x |= bit(a, b);

            masks[i + j * 8] = x;
        }
    }

    return masks;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When declaring multiple variables at once, you should not repeat the datatype.

```
int a = i + 1, b = j + 1
```